# Передача аргументов в функции

Tags: jquery, javascript

Мне надо передать аргументы в toltipUpImg() и toltipDownImg(), но проблема в том, что я не могу передать в

```
 el.onmouseover = inside;
 el.onmouseout = offside;

 function toltipImg() {
     battle = []
     phantom = document.getElementById("last_message_wrapper")

     for (var i = 1; i < 6; ++i) {
         battle[i] = document.getElementById("picture" + i)
         frontierGuard(battle[i]);
     }
 }

 function frontierGuard(inside, offside, el) {
     el.onmouseover = inside;
     el.onmouseout = offside;
 }

 function toltipUpImg(num) {
     $(".toltip_pictures" + num).css("display", "block")
     phantom.style.display = "none";
 }

 function toltipDownImg(num) {
     $(".toltip_pictures" + num).css("display", "none")
     phantom.style.display = "block";
 }
```

Ответ:

```
   function frontierGuard(el, num){
     el.onmouseover = function(){
     $(".toltip_pictures" +num).css("display", "block")  
       phantom.style.display = "none";
 };
 el.onmouseout = function(){
     $(".toltip_pictures" +num).css("display", "none")  
       phantom.style.display = "block";
}
 }
```

Comment: Вы сами то понимаете то, что понаписали? Объясните на словах, что вы хотите сделать, а этот, проти Господи, "код" - больше никому не показывайте. Поберегите нервы народу.

Answer (score 1):

Жесть.

```
function toltipUpImg(num){
  $('.toltip_pictures'+num).css("display", "block")  
}
```

Comment: да не так, короче сейчас выложу код